# coreplot pie chart data labels get cut off depending on the data

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart

I am relatively new to ios and am using ios coreplot to draw a pie chart. 
I am using ios 7 and working with coreplot 1.3 (the latest version as of today).

I am struggling with ensuring that the core plot data labels show up correctly.

In the following figure, as you can see the data label for one of the two slices is chopped off (as marked by the arrow).

[image: Pie chart with one data label chopped off]

How do you ensure that this does not happen and that the data labels show correctly no matter what the data is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot data labels are clipped by the plot area. Make sure it is big enough to contain the pie and any labels.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct though I ended up adjusting various parameters to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adjusting offsets of the enclosing rect and moving the legend down.